# how to open new tab and run script on the loaded site (typescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, window.open, inject

is it possible to open a site like this

```
window.open(‘https://example.com’);
```

and run a simple script on opened tab, that for example opens side menu?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: No, that's not possible. That would be a big security hole. If you control the destination page, you can add a query parameter to the link in the source page and trigger a function on load in the destination page if the query parameter is set.

Comment: yes i was thinking about this solution but i wanted to ask. its my page too so i need to handle the query param.. thank you :)